# How can I set a WMIC Variable in a batch file?

Tags: variables, batch-file, wmic

I created this simple batch file and it sets the variable twice.  Once with the answer I'm looking for, and then a second time blank which erases the variable.

```html
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%f in ('WMIC PRODUCT WHERE "Name like "%%iTunes%%"" get name') do set "myVar=%%f"
echo %myVar%
```

It gives me the below result.

```html
C:\Batch>disktest

C:\Batch>for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %f in ('WMIC PRODUCT WHERE "Name like "%iTun
es%"" get name') do set "myVar=%f"

" \Batch>set "myVar=Name

" \Batch>set "myVar=iTunes

" \Batch>set "myVar=

C:\Batch>echo
ECHO is on.

C:\Batch>
```

So somewhere I'm not escaping correctly with a ^ or I don't know what I'm missing.  Can anyone help me out?

This is Windows 7x64 but I'd also like to use it in XP SP3 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments with the newly discovered wmic :) I think your problem is that, by default, it will list the results you want along with the title of the column first and following empty line at the end.

To filter the results from wmic, add `| FIND "xxx"`, e.g.,

```
wmic product where "name like 'xxx'" get name | find "xxx"
```

This will filter out the line containing the title (which is why you're getting "Name" in your results) and the final blank line.

In fact, on further reflection, you may be able to remove the "where" clause completely, replacing it with the "find", so:

```
wmic product get name | find "xxx"
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian, I went with the first one you suggested.  This is what I have now. 

`for /f "tokens=1-5 delims= " %%A in ('wmic product get name^,version ^| find "iTunes"') do set "myVar=%%A"`  NOTE the ^ carrot I used to break out for the pipe | and comma.  This for use in a batch.
echo %myVar%

Comment: Also @Ian, I couldn't vote this up because I don't have enough creds yet.  But I marked it as the answer.

Comment: @DanO. you're welcome :)  You're on your way now.  Get answering some questions!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was:

```
wmic nic get name, index

set /p IndexOfAdapter= "What Adapter's index would you select? "

FOR /F "delims==" %%x IN ('WMIC NIC WHERE index^="%IndexOfAdapter%" GET name ^| FIND /V "Name" ^| FIND " "') DO (SET BOOK=%%x)
```

now I get the name of the adapter I want to disable or enable and avoid  the null answer or Name answer. With the first FIND I filter the Name and with the second the blank.
To test the script, add at the end

```
echo %BOOK%
```